# How to get address location from latitude and longitude in Google Map.?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

So I have latitude and longitude Like `44.4647452` and `7.3553838`. I need to get address like: Milan, Italy, str. Kennedy 89.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Simply pass latitude, longitude and your Google API Key to the following query string, you will get a json array, fetch your city from there.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Note: Ensure that no space exists between the latitude and longitude values when passed in the latlng parameter.

[Click here to get an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key)

Comment: sensor = false :P or you can just omit that parameter entirely now

Comment: @user3308043 Do we need to register our application for above google api call?

Comment: @UmangKothari No, you don't need to register an app for this api call only !!!

Comment: @Kirankumar, And number of calls are limited?? Btw thank you!

Comment: No @UmangKothari, there is no limit of calls too :)

Comment: @KirankumarDafda -- I am using the above URL in PHP and usually it works very well - however sometimes returns null data? Have you ever seen that issue and any suggestions? It is very intermittent but does happen. The latlng is valid and previously returned a valid address but on a second call, or third call, or nth call for same latng will return a null for address? Any thoughts on why? I rarely use this URL more than a few times a day.

Comment: @NealDavis try adding url with your lat long into browser's address bar and refresh page until you get the error message other than your required output and try resolving that error will work for you.

Comment: not valid anymore :  "error_message": "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.

Comment: Davvit: I have updated the answer.

Comment: How I can get the first address from ResponseBody? Like .getFirstAddress()?

Answer (score 17):

What your looking for is Reverse Geo Coding. Have a look at this example here. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Answer (score 9):

You have to make one ajax call to get the required result, in this case you can use Google API to get the same

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true/false
```

Build this kind of url and replace the lat long with the one you want to. do the call and response will be in JSON, parse the JSON and you will get the complete address up to street level

Comment: This is great. How do I retrieve the "formatted address" from the call?

Comment: you have to parse this with https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: @DineshPrajapati Do we need to register our application for above google api call

Comment: Not required for simple REST call

Comment: How I can get the first address from ResponseBody? Like .getFirstAddress()? –

Comment: @Cipri you just need to learn how to parse the JSON and you will be able to get any object which is present in the response.

Comment: Done it. I am able to use it. However, I am having a trouble using it, it gives me the same address if I change place. I have to activate airplane mode and deactivate so it changes to the corect location. Any idea why?

Comment: @Cipri - You have to keep this code in some trigger (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener) so that whenever the location changes it will give you an updated location.