# Isit possible to find the Current Location in Android using Latitude Longitude and Altitude

Tags: android

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

OnCreate

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_location_main);

    //All textView
    textViewNetLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewNetLat);
    textViewNetLng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewNetLng);
    textViewGpsLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewGpsLat);
    textViewGpsLng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewGpsLng);
}


public void onDestroy() {

    //Remove GPS location update
    if(glocManager != null){
        glocManager.removeUpdates(glocListener);
        Log.d("ServiceForLatLng", "GPS Update Released");
    }

    //Remove Network location update
    if(nlocManager != null){
        nlocManager.removeUpdates(nlocListener);
        Log.d("ServiceForLatLng", "Network Update Released");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

//This is for Lat lng which is determine by your wireless or mobile network
public class MyLocationListenerNetWork implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        nlat = loc.getLatitude();
        nlng = loc.getLongitude();

        //Setting the Network Lat, Lng into the textView
        textViewNetLat.setText("Network Latitude:  " + nlat);
        textViewNetLng.setText("Network Longitude:  " + nlng);

        Log.d("LAT & LNG Network:", nlat + " " + nlng);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.d("LOG", "Network is OFF!");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.d("LOG", "Thanks for enabling Network !");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}



  //This is for Lat lng which is determine by your device GPS
    public class MyLocationListenerGPS implements LocationListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            glat = loc.getLatitude();
            glng = loc.getLongitude();

            //Setting the GPS Lat, Lng into the textView
            textViewGpsLat.setText("GPS Latitude:  " + glat);
            textViewGpsLng.setText("GPS Longitude:  " + glng);

            Log.d("LAT & LNG GPS:", glat + " " + glng);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.d("LOG", "GPS is OFF!");
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.d("LOG", "Thanks for enabling GPS !");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }
    }

       public void showLoc(View v) {

        //Location access ON or OFF checking
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
        boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean networkWifiStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        //If GPS and Network location is not accessible show an alert and ask user to enable both
        if(!gpsStatus || !networkWifiStatus)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GetLocationMainActivity.this);

            alertDialog.setTitle("Make your location accessible ...");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Your Location is not accessible to us.To show location you have to enable it.");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.warning);
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remember to show    location you have to enable it !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
 //IF GPS and Network location is accessible
            else
        {
            nlocManager   =     (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            nlocListener = new MyLocationListenerNetWork();
            nlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 1, 0, nlocListener);


            glocManager  =      (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            glocListener = new MyLocationListenerGPS();
            glocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  1000 * 1, 0, glocListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Looks similar:
[Google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511597/how-to-get-address-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map)

It is javasript, but you can use the Google api in andriod as well :-)

Comment: Isit possible for me to obtain the altitude ?

Comment: this seems not so easy. you can have a look at this: http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm

Comment: I wanna find the altitude thru normal coding is that possible ?

Comment: You need to get the altitude from some data source. I don't have a better solution right now.