# Ionic: Reverse Geocoding

Tags: angularjs, cordova, gps, ionic-framework

I am integrating GPS Services into my application. I have added and injected the Cordova GPS plugin.
I am able to retrieve the longitude and the latitude as shown on the ngCordova documentation on gps. This is my approach:

```
.controller('geoLocationCtrl', function($scope,$window) {
    $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            $scope.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        })

        console.log(position);
    })
})
```

My challenge is how can I use the above to return the current address, state and country of the user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process of turning a longitude and latitude into a human readable address is called **Reverse Geocoding**. Many map APIs support that like Google Maps and Here Maps. Here is how you can do it using Google Maps API

**Add Google Maps JavaScript API**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
```

**Query the API**: here is an angular controller sample

```
app.controller('geoLocationCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.lat = position.Coordinates.latitude;
      $scope.lng = position.Coordinates.longitude;

      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.lng);
      var request = {
        latLng: latlng
      };
      geocoder.geocode(request, function(data, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (data[0] != null) {
            alert("address is: " + data[0].formatted_address);
          } else {
            alert("No address available");
          }
        }
      })
      console.log(position);
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Using the above answer the application shows a white screen. See edited for the updated code.

Comment: you have code errors in your snippet, first access the variables from $scope in this line 
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.lng);

And you have a couple of missing brackets at the end. I will edit my answer with the full code

Comment: No alert was triggered, whether address was returned or not returned but the long and lat displays

Comment: can you debug the code and tell me where is it failing for you? do you get any response at all from the geocode call?

Comment: with no errors in console? can you please elaborate on the behaviour you are facing so that I can help?

Comment: Hi Hisham, On ionic serve command, it works on chrome browser. On building and deployed to android device, geocode is not returned. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100959/discussion-between-hisham-abdel-hafez-and-jng).

Comment: How can I get the only city name from latlng using geocoder?

Answer (score 0):

you need to find out the address and other details using the lat and long values: [How to get address location from latitude and longitude in Google Map.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511597/how-to-get-address-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map)