# Click on Google Maps API and get the address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The following code allows to get the coordinates, on click.
But **how to get the address or city name or region name or country on click on the map, with Google Maps API?**

```js
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.38,2.18);
var myOptions = { zoom: 13, center: myLatlng}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {alert(event.latLng);});
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Pass the `event.latLng` trough the geocoder could be an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get address location from latitude and longitude in Google Map.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511597/how-to-get-address-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can pass the `event.latLng` trough the Geocoder to get the address:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.38, 2.18);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': event.latLng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        alert(results[0].formatted_address);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qeop8ud/)

Comment: Thanks @putvande !  Would you know how to automatically display, in a <div> the city name of the *center of the map*, each time we change position in the map (ie pan/zoom) ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that of the top of my head. Might be worth searching SO as there might be an answer to it.

Comment: you could use infowindow, then put <div> inside ,have a look my answer

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get only one result by only lat,lng from google api, but you could get some results by search lat,lng and a keyword in a radius.

the only way get specific place information you need search by its placeID

```
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.38,2.18);
var myOptions = { zoom: 13, center: myLatlng}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
var infoWindow;
var service;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var request = {
        location: event.latLng,
        keyword: 'food',
        radius:500
    };
    service.radarSearch(request, callback);

});
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.error(status);
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
        addMarker(result);
    }
}

function addMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        icon: {
            url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/circle.png',
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 17)
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
            if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                console.error(status);
                return;
            }
            infoWindow.setContent(result.name+"<br>"+result.formatted_address+"<br>"+result.formatted_phone_number);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3qeop8ud/2/

Comment: Can you search by city instead of food?

Comment: becareful about results the parameter in callback function, it might contain a lot results. in the last part, you could use single result find more information  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlaceResult

Comment: @MaYubo can you post a live demo for future reference (jsfiddle or widget here) ?

Answer (score -2):

```
 m is event =====>
 code here
 const latlng = {
lat: parseFloat(e.lat),
lng: parseFloat(e.lng),};

m.view.google.maps.Geocoder.prototype.geocode({ location: latlng },
function(results, status) {
if (status =='OK') {
  if (results[1]) {
    alert(results[1].formatted_address);
  }
}});
```