# How to get specific address on google map?

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

I am using GMap.net library and I get the address, but I get the result I don't want.
`example : the address i took out`

```
2QRR+26 Cầu Giấy, Hà Nội
```

Expected actual address :

```
108 Nguyễn Phong Sắc, Dịch Vọng, Cầu Giấy, Hà Nội
```

This is the location information I got on the website google map :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqgpw.png
This is my code :

```
 private void gmap_OnMapClick(PointLatLng pointClick, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var address = getAddressFromMap(pointClick);
            if (address != null)
            {
                rtbResultAddressGG.Text = "\nAddress : " + address[0];
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to get the address !", "");
            }
        }
  private List<String> getAddressFromMap(PointLatLng point)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            List<Placemark> placemarks = null;
            var sttCode = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetPlacemarks(point, out placemarks);
            if (sttCode == GeoCoderStatusCode.OK && placemarks != null)
            {
                List<String> address = new List<string>();
                foreach (var placemark in placemarks)
                {
                   address.Add(placemark.Address);
                }
                return address;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get address location from latitude and longitude in Google Map.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511597/how-to-get-address-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking other values of your address from getAddressFromMap?From source code of the[library](https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET/blob/master/GMap.NET/GMap.NET.Core/MapProviders/Google/GoogleMapProvider.cs) you are using, it seems that it is using the reverse Geocoding to get the address of the coordinates you are passing which will return array of results from [formatted_address field](https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET/blob/master/GMap.NET/GMap.NET.Core/MapProviders/Google/GoogleMapProvider.cs#:%7E:text=ret%20%3D%20new%20Placemark(-,geoResult.results%5Bi%5D.formatted_address,-)%3B)

```
 var ret = new Placemark(geoResult.results[i].formatted_address);
```

I tried reverse geocoding the coordinate of the address above and I can see that there's indeed a formatted_address `2QRR+26 Cầu Giấy, Hà Nội` however it is not the first formatted_address returned by the array. You can see it on this https://jsfiddle.net/79v3rqm1/ where I show in the console the returned addresses and the `2QRR+26 Cầu Giấy, Hà Nội` is also included but not the first one.